# Expose a javascript api with coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I recently started using coffeescript and was curious what is the "right" way to expose an object that I create with Coffeescript to other javascript pages.  Because of coffeescripts wrapping functionality, is it acceptable behavior to call `window.coffeeObject = externalObject`.

### Example

**example.coffee**

```
externalObject = 
   method1: -> 'Return value'
   method2: -> 'Return method2'

window.myApi = externalObject
```

**example.js** -- compiled from example.coffee

```
(function() {
  var externalObject;
  externalObject = {
    method1: function() {
      return 'Return value';
    },
    method2: function() {
      return 'Return method2';
    }
  };
  window.myApi = externalObject;
}).call(this);
```

**other.js**

```
alert(myApi.method1()) // Should return "Return value"
```

Comment: it should work...does it raise some errors? are you sure you load other.js after example.js?

Comment: I'm sure it works, I think he's just asking for best practices here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep that's correct.  Alternatively you can use define `@myApi = { foo: -> }` because `this` is `window` in the root context of the file.

Comment: `window.foo` also has the advantage of making it very _explicit_ that your injecting it into global scope.

Comment: I'm guessing using the @ symbol is better because then it's portable for your node.js scripts as well, correct?

Comment: Quite right. Either `window` or `this` will work fine; stylistically, I think `window`. is preferred. You'll thank yourself if you find yourself grepping for global exports... (**Edit to respond to simul-post with brent**: Yes, `this` will automatically resolve to `exports` in Node. Note that I like to define something like `root = exports ? this` to allay any possible confusion.)

Answer (score 4):

You can simplify the syntax further, for example if you had 2 internal functions

**example.coffee**

```
myPrivateFunction = ->
    "return 1"

myPrivateFunction2 = ->
    "return 2"

@myApi = {
    myFunction : myPrivateFunction,
    myFunction2 : myPrivateFunction2
}
```

**example.js**

```
this.myApi = {
  myFunction: myPrivateFunction,
  myFunction2: myPrivateFunction2
};
```

The `@` will be `window` within the main scope of the file.

Then call from elsewhere by `window.myApi.myFunction()`

If you wanted to map the external function names to the same internal names, if you don't specify `key : value` pairs, it will just use the string value as the key by default.

**example.coffee**

```
@myApi = {
    myPrivateFunction,
    myPrivateFunction2
}
```

**example.js**

```
this.myApi = {
  myPrivateFunction: myPrivateFunction,
  myPrivateFunction2: myPrivateFunction2
};
```