# Reason behind this self invoking anonymous function variant

Tags: javascript, module, anonymous-function, coffeescript, commonjs

While looking at [code](https://github.com/sstephenson/node-coffee-project/blob/master/lib/index.js) on github, I found the following:

```
(function() {

}).call(this);
```

This is clearly a self invoking anonymous function. But why is it written this way? I'm used to seeing the canonical variant `(function() {})()`.

Is there any particular advantage to using `.call(this)` for a self invoking anonymous function?

---

Edit: It looks like some commonjs environments set `this` to a non-global value at the top level of a module. Which ones, and what do they set `this` to that you might want to preserve?

Comment: Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36636/what-is-a-closure

Comment: @Rob I don't think that's remotely what Sean is asking about in this question.

Comment: Ah, found it - definitely not a duplicate question, but the answer is similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211638/pattern-for-coffeescript-modules/5212449#5212449

Comment: Ooh, Good link @Matt. I can see there that it makes a lot of sense if the functions are nested.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542942/why-use-the-javascript-function-wrapper-added-in-coffeescript-callthis/4542979#4542979 A comment on this answer says that some commonjs environments set `this` to a non-global at the top level of a module. That would explain why you might need to preserve `this`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995510/expose-a-javascript-api-with-coffeescript/5995586#5995586 It looks like it's node that sets `this` to non-global for modules. A comment here says that `this === exports` in the node environment.

Comment: If you wonder why `.call(this)` was used instead of the normal IIFE call, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21736430/1048572) on "Why write “.call(this)” at the end of an javascript anonyms function?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.call(this)` (was actually just `()` until I changed it) ensures your top level `this` to be consistent through strict mode, `--bare` option and/or the running environment (where top level `this` doesn't point to global object).

Comment: None of that makes any sense.

Comment: Ah -- `()` and `.call(this)` are different in strict mode. Now it all makes sense. `.call(this)` provides the same context to the function is strict and lax modes.

Comment: @matyr Can you explain further with description or links about () and .call(this) what they are actually means in strict mode? I could not understand the strict mode bit.

Comment: In lax mode, if you call a function with no object, `this` is set to `window`. In strict mode, `this` is set to `undefined`. Using `.call(this)` explicitly sets `this` (inside the function) to `this` (outside the function), thus making sure that it stays as `window`, regardless of if you are in strict or lax mode.

Comment: Thanks, @SeanMcMillan. I actually understood what you wrote. I believe your explanation was much better than the answer.

Answer (score 27):

By default, invoking a function like `(function(){/*...*/})()` will set the value of `this` in the function to `window` (in a browser) irrespective of whatever the value of `this` may be in the enclosing context where the function was created.

Using `call` allows you to manually set the value of `this` to whatever you want. In this case, it is setting it to whatever the value of `this` is in the enclosing context.

Take this example:

```
var obj = {
    foo:'bar'
};

(function() {
    alert( this.foo ); // "bar"
}).call( obj );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LWFAp/

You can see that we were able to manually set the value of `this` to the object referenced by the `obj` variable.

Comment: His question asks what adding `this` to the end does, not what adding a custom object does.

Comment: @Startec: There's no difference. They'll do the same thing. He's just passing a different object so he can show that the properties of the object become available via `this` inside the function.

Comment: @sixfingeredman Right, this shows that you can set the value of this by passing in an object in the closing parens.  However, the question is, what happens when you pass in the `this` object, not some object you have instantiated. In other words, if passing in `this` just makes the value of `this` in the enclosing function `this`, why pass it in at all?

Comment: @Startec: I see what you're saying. Since they would be effectively the same (unless in strict mode), then what's the point. Though that rationale is based on global execution of the IIFE, and that detail seems to have been added to the question a bit later.

Comment: Is there an ES2015 way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

By using:

```
> (function() {
>   ...
> }).call(this);`
```

then *this* in the scope of the code (probaby the global object) is set as the function's *this* object. As far as I can tell, it's equivalent to:

```
(function(global) {
  // global references the object passed in as *this*
  // probably the global object
})(this);
```

In a browser, usually *window* is (or behaves as if it is) an alias for the global object.

Comment: The first is definitely not equivalent to the second.

Comment: It provides a reference to the outer execution context's *this* and stores it as a local variable named *global* rather than *this*. So it is equivalent, it just assigns the reference to a different property of the local activation/variable object.

Answer (score 0):

```
C={
    descript: "I'm C!<br>",
    F: function() {
        //set this to the caller context's 'this'
        (function() {
            document.write(this.descript);
        }).call(this);

        //set this to 'window' or 'undefined' depend the mode
        (function() {
            document.write(this.descript);
        })();

        //member function's 'this' is the object self
        document.write(this.descript);
    }
}

window.descript="I'm window!<br>";

C.F();
```

`(function() {}).call(this);` could set the `this` in the anonymous to the caller context `this`, in above is `C`.`(function() {})();` will set `this` to `window` or `undefined` depend the mode.

Answer (score -3):

Self-invoking function are useful to execute its content immediately when the script is loaded. This is convenient to initialize global scope elements.