# Why use (function(){}).call(this);?

Tags: javascript

I've been studying some JS libraries lately that were written by people who really knew what they were doing, and I keep seeing this pattern, and I can't find information about it. I read the docs on the .call() method, but it didn't really make sense to me. I'm hoping to get one of those good old classic in-depth SO explanations with examples.

```
(function(undefined){
   /*(insert entire library here)*/
}).call(this);
```

What is this about? Why is this a good way to write a library?

Note, sometimes the `undefined` is omitted, though I have no idea what difference it makes to put it there or not. I don't even know where the arguments are coming from, or who the caller is.

Comment: @Bergi good job marking this as a duplicate, pretty sure A. it makes no difference a year later, B. my question has a way better answer than the "duplicate."

Comment: Thank you, I do this just along the way when I see a [new duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27349669/1048572) and while searching for the canonical one I find lots of other duplicates.

Comment: Well, okay, but I think this is the canonical one.

Comment: Hm, having a closer look at your question it's actually a duplicate not only of [self invoking anonymous function .call(this) variant](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6287511/1048572) but also of [What is the purpose of a self executing function in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/592396/1048572) (or maybe one of those linked in the comments there) and [(function( window, undefined ) { })(window) syntax?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2716069/1048572). I think it's too broad for a canonical question. Of course, you can always cast a reopen vote in case you disagree :-)

Comment: The answers in the first link were not as well written as @Halcyon's answer in this one.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Let's disassemble this piece of code.

First off there is an anonymous function with **immediate invocation**. It's similar to this:

```
(function () {/**/}).call();
(new Date()).getTime(); // timestamp since 1970 jan 1 in milliseconds
```

We don't assign `new Date()` to a variable, instead we use it immediately.

---

Now why use `.call` instead of just `()`?

[`.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) is a method all `Functions` have. The first argument is what `this` will be bound to, subsequent arguments will be passed as arguments to the function. So:

```
(function () {
    console.log(this.foo); // bar
}).call({ "foo": "bar" });
```

This works in conjunction with `undefined` (see below).

`.call` is the *same* as `.apply` with one minor difference. `.apply` only takes 2 arguments, where the 2nd is an array of arguments. This would be similar:

```
(function () {}).call(this, "foo", "bar");
(function () {}).apply(this, [ "foo", "bar" ]);
```

A common use of apply is in conjunction with the magic variable `arguments`.

```
(function () {
     console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)); // [ "bar" ]
})([ "foo", "bar" ]);
```

`Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)` may look scary but really it's just `arguments.slice(1)`, but `arguments` isn't an `Array` so it doesn't have a `slice` function. We borrow `Array`s `slice` function and use `.call` to set the `this` to `arguments`. `Array.prototype.slice(arguments, 1??)` is incorrect.

---

Now why is there `this` in `.call(this)`? `this` always points to the context you're in. If you're in an instance of a class it will point to the instance and if you're in the *global scope* it will point to that. In a browser environment it is also `window`.

---

Why `undefined`? Since we did a `.call(this)` with no second argument, all arguments to our anonymous function are `undefined`. I'm not really sure *why* you need to make an explicit variable named `undefined` there. Maybe this is support for some browsers or some lint tool that likes to see `undefined` defined.

Thanks to @TedHopp. `undefined` is fickle.

```
var undefined = "foo";
console.log(undefined); // undefined

(function (undefined) {
    console.log(undefined); // "foo"
})("foo");
```

---

You can just as easily have:

```
(function () {
    /* code here */
}());
```

This is completely valid and works just the same. There might be some performance or linting benefits to use the form you posted.

Comment: This is exactly why I love stack overflow.

Comment: Really nice answer. My guess is that `undefined` in the argument list guarantees that `undefined` will have its original (lack of) value. This would insulate the code from strange contexts where `undefined` had been bound to something.

Comment: To my knowledge `undefined` is always declared (but not defined). Trying to do: `var undefined = "foo"; "foo" === undefined;` gives `false`, but maybe not in all browsers. I would expect `var undefined = "foo";` to throw an Error of some sort, to elevate `undefined` to a reserved keyword, maybe this is coming in newer (stricter) ES versions. Your link points to the ES5 spec whereas this code is written to deal with <ES5.

Comment: `undefined` is a type, but also a global variable `window.undefined`. `typeof window.undefined` retrieves `undefined`. You use `undefined` as an argument to ensure that `undefined` is really undefined in all browsers and declares it if there's any required by some lint tool as @FritsvanCampen has already said.

Comment: @RoyMiloh - The identifier `undefined` can be locally bound: `function foo(undefined) { console.log(typeof undefined); } foo(3);` will print `number`, not `undefined`. Note that `typeof window.undefined` is the _string_ `'undefined'`. According to the [ECMAScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.10), the type is `Undefined`; it's sole value is `undefined`. In ECMAScript 5, the `undefined` property of the global object is not writable; this behavior first appeared in Firefox 4 (don't know about other browsers).

Comment: `Array.prototype.slice.call` will always look scary