# self executing function invoked explicitly with call method

Tags: javascript

I've seen tons of javascript code use self executing functions like:

```
(function(){
    // ... code here
})();
```

But occasionally, I see people do this variant:

```
(function(){
    // ... code here
}).call(this);
```

**Is there some functional difference between these 2 forms? If so, what is it?**

An example of the 2nd form in the wild: https://github.com/shawnmclean/Idle.js/blob/master/build/idle.js#L160

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second form passes the value of `this` into the IIFE so `this` inside the IIFE will have the same value that it had outside the IIFE.  There are many cases where this does not make a difference, but if the IIFE is inside a scope where `this` is set to some meaningful value, then the second form will preserve that value of `this` inside the IIFE.

If `this` in the outer scope is the global object and you are not running strict mode, then the 2nd form doesn't really change anything as `this` will still be the global object inside the IIFE.

But, if `this` is any meaningful value in strict mode or any meaningful value other than the global object when not in strict mode, then the 2nd form will extend the value of `this` into the enclosure.

In the example you point to, my guess is that the second form is just being used as a common design pattern, not because there really is a reason in that particular case to do it.  In fact, if you look at the code example you pointed to, it doesn't even use the value of `this` at the top level of the IIFE so it's definitely superfluous in that specific example.

Comment: In what case is *this* not set to a "meaningful value"?

Comment: @RobG - In strict mode, `this` is often `undefined` (e.g. in any normal function call).