# Is the underscore.js IIFE syntax valid?

Tags: javascript, syntax, underscore.js

I just took a look at the [underscore.js source code](http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js) and when i strip the source code down to its bare containing IIFE it looks like this:

```
(function() {

}.call(this));
```

I always used the syntax with outer parantheses `(function() {}).call(this);` and wondered if this syntax is also valid and common?

Comment: Yes this syntax is correct :)

Comment: Why would the outer parentheses be wrong?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi i was expecting that the outer paranthesis is needed so the anonymous function can be treated as an expression e.g. `(function() {}).call(this)` or `+function() {}.call(this)`. But why does `(function() {}.call(this))` execute but `function() {}.call(this)` does not?

Comment: See the duplicate on what this construct does. If you're only looking for the parenthesis syntax, see [Location of parenthesis for auto-executing anonymous JavaScript functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3384504/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking about the location of the outer `)` specifically, then whether it's located immediately after the closing brace or after the entire expression [doesn't matter for the most part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938802/are-function-and-function-functionally-equal-i). Either way doesn't make a difference to how the IIFE is executed.

The only difference here is the `.call(this)`, which is invoked as a member of the function expression — a typical IIFE has just the inner parentheses immediately following the closing brace. The reason `.call(this)` is used is detailed in a number of other answers including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287511/reason-behind-this-self-invoking-anonymous-function-variant/6287571#6287571).

Comment: But `function() {}.call(this)` can't be executed, i know the trick via `+function() {}.call(this)` but why would wrapping it inside paranthesis change how the inner expression is executed?

Comment: @Nick Russler: Wrapping it inside parentheses or `+`ing it tells the parser that it's a function expression, not a function declaration.

Comment: So it's just a syntax thing. It seemed weird to me that enclosing paranthesis could change how the inner code is executed.